# How to cover up a shelf that is too short for its brackets

Tags: shelving, brackets

I made a slight miscalculation when hanging some shelves. All three rows of shelves that I hung have brackets centered on every other stud. The wood I bought to lay on top of them is 8' long.

When I lay the shelf centered across the brackets, the edges are found to be sitting on the middle of the brackets. I am not too concerned about this structurally, there won't be anything too heavy on the edges. However, this is unsightly in my opinion. What would you recommend to hide this error?

[image: full view of 3 rows of shelves with brackets centered on studs]

[image: the shelf only makes it to half the thickness of the bracket]
[image: same problem as other side]

Comment: Mount the end brackets to the side of the stud centre.

Comment: It seems like drilling the screws right next to an existing hole is a bad idea. Should I fill the existing hole with wood glue or filler first?